# How to transmit screen and control device via mac while running app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, ios-simulator

I'd like to test apps on device in the same way like on simulator - app runs on real device but I see screen on mac and I can interact with it using mouse. Im just tired of putting phone to my hand all the time. Developing on windows phone allows it, so It would be nice to have it here. Thank you

Comment: No, you can't. Wish there is such a feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Holdsworth on [Remote Xcode plugin](https://github.com/johnno1962/Remote):

> “Remote is a plugin for Xcode that allows you to control an iPhone
>   from a window on your Mac during development.”

I just found this. You can control device via mac.